# Jekyll - create new site scaffold in existing project

Tags: jekyll

To create a new site scaffold with Jekyll, the command is `jekyll new <site_name>` where `<site_name>` is the new project's root folder name. If the `<site_name>` value is an existing folder, an error is thrown: `Conflict: <site_name> exists and is not empty.`

**Is there a Jekyll command that makes it possible to create a new site scaffold inside an existing project?** The purpose would be to adapt an existing static site to take advantage of templating etc in Jekyll.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can force Jekyll to create a new site in a non empty folder by using the `--force` flag.

```
jekyll new <site_name> --force
```

Comment: The website should probably document that better. I've had to do what the second answer said many times before when all I had was a readme in the repo.

Answer (score 10):

From the official Jekyll docs:

If you wish to install jekyll into an existing directory, you can do so by running `jekyll new .` from within the directory instead of creating a new one. If the existing directory isn’t empty, you’ll also have to pass the `--force` option like so `jekyll new . --force`.

Here's is the link to the official site's quick start page:
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/

Comment: should be selected answer

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to create a new subfolder, run `jekyll new .` and start copying the files from your existing folder into your new folder with Jekyll.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, and I think it's probably the best way considering the alternative might overwrite existing files. It was simple for me to cut and paste from the new jekyll scaffold into the existing project.